# How to setup pagination in REST API url?

Tags: rest, api

How to setup the Pagination if we have REST API url.

I have a REST API url from workday and shared with vendor to access the data using RESTFUL call. But seems it contains large amount of data and application runs too slow, vendor wants to manage with pagination.
How can we share the REST url with pagination?

Here is the example of my REST url:
https://workday.com/service/customreport/ACN/ABC/DEF

Here is the example of my REST url:
https://workday.com/service/customreport/ACN/ABC/DEF

Comment: Hi, were u able to solve this pagination?

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to have a separate resource (a different URI) for each page of data.  Pages get [linked](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988) together, often using the relations first/prev/next/last as registered in the [IANA link registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml).

A common spelling choice for the URI is to encode into the identifier the parameters required by the server to generate the page dynamically.  Paging is not hierarchical, so it is common (but not required) to describe those parameters in the [query part](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) of the identifier.  Key value pairs in the query string are easily produced by HTML form processing, which is another argument in favor of this approach.

The names of the parameters don't actually matter, so long as they satisfy the [URI spelling constraints](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).  There are a number of ways you could do it; but I think the best place to start is by looking at the [timelines in the Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/guides/working-with-timelines).  max-id/since-id/count is a reasonable way to describe a slice of data from an append-only collection.